# To generate key for AWS server using ssh-keygen from .pem for PuTTY

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, ssh-keys, putty

AWS gave me a private key in the format of `.pem`. I am trying to use it with PuTTY but failed and I read I need to generate a key with PuTTYgen but PuTTYgen is only for Windows. So I am trying to use the Linux command `ssh-keygen`. But what is exactly the command that can generate such a key that PuTTY can use?

BTW, I can connect with console using ssh without problem with the `.pem` file.

Comment: As Martin's answer mentions, putty and puttygen are available for Linux.  In Ubuntu for example, puttygen is part of the putty-tools package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert the `.pem` key to the `.ppk` key using the *nix command-line version of the `puttygen` use:

```
puttygen mykey.pem -o mykey.ppk
```

See the [`puttygen` man page](https://manpages.debian.org/stable/putty-tools/puttygen.1.en.html).

There's [PuTTY rpm](https://pkgs.org/download/putty) and "putty-tools" package available for many *nix distributions.

---

The `.ppk` format is proprietary to PuTTY, so tools outside of PuTTY toolset (like the `ssh-keygen`) do not support it.

Note that you can convert the key on Windows using GUI version of PuTTYgen and still use the converted key on Linux.

Comment: I meant to use ssh command in terminal to connect instead of putty. Sorry, in fact puttygen is available when I install putty in opensuse. I thought there's a package called puttygen. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the provided PEM file to PPK file using Puttygen tool in Windows.

- Open puttygen and click on import key option in the menu.
- Once it is imported you will see the button which says "Save Private
  Key".
- Save it as a xyz.ppk file name and they load that ppk file in putty
  and login.

Hope this helps.